# Setting up a UITableViewCell subclass in code

Tags: ios, ios6, uitableview

I am reading the apple docs on setting up custom subclasses of UITableViewCell - [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html)

In this example I need to setup a custom cell which does not have a NIB/storyboard file. The apple docs provide an example of using a predefined style and configuring that but not creating a completely custom layout.

1. How should the cell be called in.. `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` ?

I am looking to have a completely custom layout so is this correct? As the cell is being called initWithStyle...?

```
MESLeftMenuCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if(cell == nil)  {
    cell = [[MESLeftMenuCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
```

1. In the custom cell subclass how/where should I implement the setup of the views within the contentView?
   Which method is called for the init, would it be initWithStyle as above? If so, can I simply create the cell outlets in there once only?

Then in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` can I access the outlets as i.e. cell.MainLabel.text ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of iOS 6, you no longer need to check whether the dequeued cell is nil.

What you would do is as follows:

In the viewDidLoad method of the view controller containing the table view you could say

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[MyCellClass class] forCellReuseIdentifier:MyCellIdentifier];
```

This results in your dequeueReusablecellWithIdentifier call to never return nil. In essence, in the background, initWithStyle is called. So you would set your stuff up when overriding that function.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have been shown to set up my Collection View Cells in their custom class. I know you are using a tableview but this is threw me for a while so decided to add here. Hopefully it helps you.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    [self commonInit];
}
return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:encoder];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)commonInit
{
    // set up your instance
}
```

To access the outlets of that cell I just add outlets to the header file of the custom class  and you can easily access them.